# C++: Work with a pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, hashtable

I am struggling with the syntax needed to declare, create, and manipulate a pointer to an array of list objects. I'm creating a hash table template class for a course assignment, using chaining to deal with has collisions.

The way my hash table is supposed to be is an array of `list` objects. `std::list` is the only standard library data class I'm allowed to use for the assignment, so vector is out.

My questions are:
How do I declare a pointer to an array of std::list? I have:

```
private:
    std::list<T> * table;
```

How do I create the array? I have:

```
table = new std::list<T>[3]; // start with table size 3
```

I think I have the declaration and construction right, but I'm not 100% sure. Lastly, how do I interact with the list's? I've got:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _tableSize; i++) { // _tableSize is the array's size
        if (!table[0][i].empty()) {
            table[0][i].push_back(thing);
        }
    }
```

Somehow table[0][i] seems wrong to access a cell of the array that `table` points to. What should it look like?

Comment: How about a `list<list<T>>`?  That only uses `list`.

Comment: @James Alas, that's not allowed for the assignment. It has to be (a pointer to) an array of list objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `table` is a `std::list*`, `table[i][j]` means `(table + i)->operator[](j)`; that is, it calls a member function (with argument `j`) on the `std::list` object starting at address `table + i`.

It follows that, since `std::list` doesn't overload `[]`, `table[0][i].empty()` is wrong (doubly wrong if `T` in `std::list<T>` is such that it hasn't a member function `empty`).

Shortly, I think that what you need is a simple `table[list_index_on_array].empty()` to check for emptiness.

Everything else looks ok.

Comment: std::list doesn't implement operator[].

Comment: table is supposed to point to any array, not be the array itself. Does this still work for that situation?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Actually, there're no arrays in C++, just pointers. So any pointer is a pointer to an array.

Comment: @Pixie: C++ very much does have arrays.

Comment: OK, if it's about compile-time types, then it does have. But in this case it doesn't matter, I think. What I wanted to say is it doesn't have such objects like built-in arrays, only memory buffers and array-like classes.

Comment: @Pixie: an "int a[5]" is not a "built-in array"?

Comment: No, in runtime it's just a memory buffer.

Comment: @Pixie: I don't understand the distinction. Would you say that C++ also doesn't have objects of class type because at run time the object is just a memory buffer?

Comment: Objects don't have loads of metadata at runtime, but they may have at least RTTI information, and arrays cannot. But I admit you're right and C++ lacks runtime information about particulary everything. The only thing I wanted to explain to OP is that when he declares a pointer, he can use it as an array.

Comment: So in short, what should my declaration look like, what should my construction (using `new`) look like, and what should accessing an element look like?

Comment: I got some help from a classmate. I now have `list<T> * table = new list<T>[size]`, which points to an array of lists like I need it to. Then I access with `table[index].push_back(thing)`

Answer (score 0):

If class `Foo` has a pointer to an array of lists of T, it's declaration would look something like this:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_LISTS 100

template <typename T>
class Foo {
    std::list<T> (*table)[NUMBER_OF_LISTS];
    Foo (std::size_t = 1);
};
```

And, to initialize it, the constructor for Foo could do the allocation like:

```
template <typename T>
inline Foo<T>::Foo (std::size_t entries)
    : table(new std::list<T>[entries][100]) {}
```

Now, the code you have to access `table` will work, but you could also do:

```
(*table)[i].push_back(something);
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you use `[0]` for? Just `[i]` would be enough.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: This is. The only thing you did wrong is using [0]. Everything else is ok.

Comment: Ok, looking at what I needed to change, yes this is technically an answer. But it was far too unclear to be of any help.

Comment: You had a problem and I told you how to solve it. You didn't ask for explanations. But the choice is yours, of course.